# Should one always NOT set the value attribute for an HTML input of type password?

Tags: html, passwords

For example:

```
<input value="userspassword" type="password"/>
```

I'm tempted to do this in certain situations on log in, sign up, edit account, etc pages. Should it never be done as it could be a security vulnerability?

**edit:** I'm not talking about as a placeholder, but as re-displaying a password the user entered on a form that didn't pass validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to use the password as part of a Sticky Form, that's fine if you are using SSL and POST.

Comment: to clarify I'm not talking about as a placeholder. see post edit.

Comment: what about the value being cached in the browser?

Comment: If someone get a hold of the users computer, or has access to their Browser there is always a security risk, if the user has the Browser set to remember passwords. A hacker would have to access their cache, which is unlikely. Don't use JavaScript to store any information, use PHP and `<form method='post'>`. Nothing is 100% safe. You can't eliminate the risk, just reduce it.